# Is there such a thing as complex rational numbers and does it have the same properties as the usual complex numbers as extension of the real numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I've been wondering if there is any use to defining a set that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^2$ (in the same way that $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$).

I immediately see a problem with *e.g.* Cauchy's theorem (there's no $\pi$ available) and perhaps even defining a "analytical function" concept because there are series defined in $\mathbb{Q}$ that do not converge within $\mathbb{Q}$.

Still, I wonder if there's a way around these difficulties.

Comment: Well you can build the extension field $\mathbb Q (i)$, so there _is_ such a thing. What do you want to know _about it_?

Comment: @AlexR Could is be used to say, define useful quantum physics, and would the limitations of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{i})$ be in any way meaningful when interpreted physically?

Answer (score 1):

People do indeed define the "complex rationals", i.e. the extension of the rationals by $i$, often cqlled the [Gaussian rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational).  The question is what you want to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a field exists.  It's sometimes called $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.  It's a degree two extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

It has the property that some polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ have roots in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.  For instance, $X^2+1$.

However, the complex numbers are *algebraically closed*—any polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ has roots in $\mathbb{C}$.  $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ does not have this property: $X^2-2$ has no root in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Also, the complex numbers are *complete* as a metric space, meaning that Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ converge to elements of $\mathbb{C}$.  $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ does not have this property, either, making it hard to analyze functions defined on this space.